# Rails how can I get all custom validate methods that defined in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I have a Model called Person.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate_presence_of :name
  validate :check_card_number

  def check_card_number
    errors.add(:card_number, "Card Number can't be blank") if card_number.blank?
      -----
      # some other stuffs here
      ----
  end 
end
```

If I am calling the below method I am getting the validator class name

```
Person.validators_on(:name) => [ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator]
```

but for

```
Person.validators_on(:card_number) => []
```

How can I check I am validating the presence of card number?

Comment: Try using a different name than `card_number` for the card_number validator method, since card_number is used to access the Person model's card_number field.

Comment: why are you using a custom validator for presence check, or is that for the example only ?

Comment: Your card_number method appears to be calling itself.  is `card_number` a field in your model's database table?  If so then this method will overwrite the "getter" for it, which i don't think you want to do.  If you want to use a custom validation then make a new name for it.

Comment: @Anand yes, actually the custom method name is check_card_number, I updated the Qn with this.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady yes because I am checking other stuffs related to card number (for example: card_number already exists then adding some custom error, comparing the card_number with other params values etc) in the check_card_number custom method, and other codes also.

Answer (score 1):

[`validate`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations.rb#L132-L141) method actually inserts a method(which is passed as an argument) into a [callback chain](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb#L491-L507). Because, it doesn't use any [defined validators](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/3-2-stable/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations) from `ActiveModel`. So, it can be accessed like so:

```
Person.send(:get_callbacks, :validate).detect{ |cb| cb.filter == :check_card_number }
```

However, condition in method "`card_number.blank?`" looks from presence of `card_number` attribute. Which in my guess would be a good fit for:

```
validate_presence_of :name, :card_number
```

Comment: I can't use validate_presence_of, because I am checking other stuffs related to card number (for example: card_number already exists then adding some custom error, comparing the card_number with other params values etc) in the check_card_number custom method, and other codes also. Can you update your answer, because I changed the method name to check_card_number

Comment: @Abhi : Then use uniqueness validator as well. Idea is to use custom validator only when you're doing a very specific customized checks, for example card numbers are valid, not some random number 1111-1111-1111-1111 etc.

Comment: yes, I meant this only, doing some more stuffs inside

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
ModelName._validate_callbacks.to_a.reject { |validation| validation.filter.to_s.starts_with?('validate_associated_records') }
```

Here 'reject' is used to ignore some default validations.

Answer (score -1):

I doubt this is possible. Just tried `Person.validators` but it does not return custom validation **methods**.

If you really want `validators_on` and `validators` to return all validators, you can [create a custom `ActiveModel::Validator`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators) class and register it in your model with `validates_with`.

Comment: Yes, if we use `validates_with MyValidator`, then validators method returns `MyValidator`. But I want to check whether presence check is calling on an particular attribute.